# Whitelist port from specific source IP and destination IP

Tags: iptables

I am looking to whitelist port 22, but only for specific source and destination IP addresses.

I am aware of how to do this using iptables for a specific source IP:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s YourIP --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

The destination IP is what I am not sure on.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a router that gets hit first by connections? You can define the destination with `-d DST_IP`,

Answer (score 0):

The command you have would work if you executed this on the destination machine, where you would allow **YourIP** to have access to port 22. If you want to use a destination IP, you'd have to use the OUTPUT chain. I'm not sure what the scenario here is, so I'm just showing an example. Be very careful with iptables

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: That doesn't allow me to specify the source IP, which is essential as this is a virtualization node with many IPs.

Comment: Then format your question better, so it's clear that this is going to be executed on a hypervisor

Answer (score 0):

I got this figured out :)

I'm using the following rule to block port 22 for all VPS' on the hypervisor:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -o br0 -p tcp --sport 22 -j DROP
```

And the following rule to whitelist specific VPS' IP addresses if needed:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -o br0 -s VPSIPADDRESS -d REMOTEIP -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

This has been fully tested and is working absolutely perfectly, just like I wanted it to :)